# Issue with accessing new Liferay instance?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have created a new liferay instance with the following details,

Web ID: **demo5.floor.com**

Virtual Host: **demo5.floor.com**

Mail Domain: **floor.com**

Max Users: **100**

Active: **Yes**

After giving the above above details I saved the portal instance. The instance got saved successfully. After that I restated the liferay server and tried to access the newly added portal instance with following URL in the browser, http://demo5.floor.com But I am not able to access the page (Web page is not available).

Did I miss anything in the portal instance creation process? Do I need to add the domain names anywhere in the system properties or property files?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this **demo5.floor.com** a public host??

If not, Please add host entry in your local system for

> 127.0.0.1 demo5.floor.com

after that, hit following URL in browser

> http://demo5.floor.com:8080

if you are running on port 8080.